# Hide default date input menu on Firefox and Edge

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, datepicker

I'm developing a custom date picker component with Vuejs using an i`<input type="text">`. I want to use a custom date picker menu, so I have to hide or disable the default one, for instance this:

[image]

How can I do that with CSS or JS?

Comment: you mean the default value as 05/07/2018

Comment: No, I mean the dialog with the calendar. I've implemented my custom dialog, I only need to hide the default one

Comment: Please share your findings if you have solved it

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to hide the default picker in every browser, especially for Edge (not the chromium-based version) there seem to be no way to hide it.

To hide the picker on Chrome and Firefox, I've simply overridden the `onclick` method of the input:

```js
onClick (e) {
    e.preventDefault() // Prevent the default picker from showing up
    showPicker(this) // Show the custom picker
}
```

If the user is using Edge, I simply disable the custom picker and use the default one. I used [bowser](https://github.com/lancedikson/bowser) to detect the current browser:

```js
const Bowser = require("bowser");
const browser = Bowser.getParser(window.navigator.userAgent);
const isEdge = browser.satisfies({ 'microsoft edge': '>0' });
```